# Python equivalent of php FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH

Tags: php, python, utf-8, ascii, data-cleaning

Parsing a large data set of poor quality data converted from pysical form using OCR and using PostgreSQL COPY to insert .csv files into psql.  Some records have ASCII bytes that are causing errors to import into postgres since I want the data in UTF-8 varchar(), as I believe that using a TEXT type column would not produce this error.

```
DataError: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xd6 0x53
CONTEXT:  COPY table_name, line 112809
```

I want to filter all these bytes before writing to the csv file.

I believe something like PHP's FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH (http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php) would work since it can remove all  high ASCII value > 127.

Is there such a function in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encode your string to ASCII, ignoring errors, then decode that back to a string.

```
text = "ƒart"
text = text.encode("ascii", "ignore").decode()
print(text)     # art
```

If you are starting with a byte string in UTF-8, then you just need to decode it:

```
bites = "ƒart".encode("utf8")
text = bites.decode("ascii", "ignore")
print(text)     # art
```

This works specifically with UTF-8 because multi-byte characters always use values outside of the ASCII range, so partial characters are never stripped out. It mightn't work so well with other encodings.